# How can I copy data from textarea in HTML which is not in Form element using HtmlUnit in java?

Tags: java, htmlunit

I am using https://www.base64decode.org/ to decode the encoded text using htmlunit in java.

Here is html code of the site

```
  <form name="convert_text" method="post" action="/">
    <textarea name="input" placeholder="Type (or paste) here..."></textarea>
    <button type="submit" name="decode" value="decode"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>DECODE<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></button>
    <select name="charset"><option value="UTF-8">UTF-8</option><option value="ASCII">ASCII</option><option value="CP1256">CP1256</option><option value="ISO-8859-1">ISO-8859-1</option><option value="ISO-8859-2">ISO-8859-2</option><option value="ISO-8859-6">ISO-8859-6</option><option value="ISO-8859-15">ISO-8859-15</option><option value="Windows-1252">Windows-1252</option></select>
    <span>You may also select input charset.</span>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </form>
  <textarea name="output" placeholder="Result goes here..."></textarea>
```

Here is my Decode.java code

```
    public class Decode {
public static void de(String str){
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
    webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
    try{
        HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("https://www.base64decode.org/");
        HtmlForm form = page.getFormByName("convert_text");


        HtmlTextArea content = form.getTextAreaByName("input");
        content.setText(str);

         HtmlElement button = form.getButtonByName("decode");
         button.click();


         HtmlTextArea contentArea = form.getTextAreaByName("output"); //can't use Htmlform, as textarea is outside form element 
        String st = contentArea.getText();
        System.out.println(st);

        } 
    catch(Exception e){System.out.print(e);}



}
}
```

How can i set text in second textarea (it is outside form element)?

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a working example:

- use the type() method if you like to simulate user input
- use getElementByName() for finding elements having a name (this page http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/gettingStarted.html has some more hints about finding elements)
- Your code has to look at the resulting page being the result/response of clicking the button

Hope that helps.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "SHRtbFVuaXQgaXMgZ3JlYXQ=";
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
    webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);

    try{
        HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("https://www.base64decode.org/");
        HtmlForm form = page.getFormByName("convert_text");

        HtmlTextArea content = form.getTextAreaByName("input");
        content.type(str);

        HtmlElement button = form.getButtonByName("decode");
        HtmlPage resultPage = button.click();

        HtmlTextArea contentArea = (HtmlTextArea) resultPage.getElementByName("output"); 
        String st = contentArea.getText();
        System.out.println("Result: '" + st + "'");

    } catch(Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @RBRi. It worked. For the small encoded string the site returns decoded string in the textarea but for the large string it download the decoded string as a pdf. But when I use large encoded string it shows "Waiting for local host". I have also tried                                                   
       """"" if (content.getText() != null && !content.getText().isEmpty())
        {
             st = contentArea.getText();
            System.out.println("Result: '" + st + "'");
        } """"""

Comment: Will have a look at this during the next days, please be a bit patient. What do you mean by 'a large encoded string"?

Comment: I am uploading files through a jsp webpage. The files can be txt, pdf, .py,  .c, etc...But mysql stores pdf as a binary/image. So, I have apply Base64 encoding on it and stored in my database column as a string and the encoded string stored is too long for the pdf.

Comment: And why not using the java build in base64 support or apache commons codec?